# Dynamically filtering a DataGridView control

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I have a datagridview control showing data from my SQL Server DB using a DataTable called m_DeletedItemsDT.

Above the grid I have two datatimepicker controls so the user can select a beginning and end date, then click the cmdFilterData which gets a filtered dataset from the db and refreshes the grid using the below query:

```
"SELECT * FROM ReturnUnpaidData_Audit WHERE [AuditDateTime]<='" & Me.dtpEndDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "' AND [AuditDateTime]>='" & Me.dtpStartDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "'"
```

What I would like is rather than another round trip to the database, for the filtering to happen on the grid, or on the datatable which is called **m_DeletedItemsDT** and declared at form/class level..

I tried looking at [Filter DataGridView with the text entered in TextBox in WinForms](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/431281/Filter-DataGridView-with-the-text-entered-in-TextB)
 but it isn't really what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked it out with a little trial and error:

```
Dim dv As New System.Data.DataView

dv.Table = m_DeletedItemsDT
' "Server like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'";
dv.RowFilter = "[AuditDateTime]<='" & Me.dtpEndDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "' AND [AuditDateTime]>='" & Me.dtpStartDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "'"
dgvDeletedRecords.DataSource = dv
```

and in the event of the *cmdClearFilter* button I just do the below:

```
    Dim dv As New System.Data.DataView

    Me.chkAUtoDates.Checked = False
    '        Call m_GetData()
    With dv
        .Table = m_DeletedItemsDT
        .RowFilter = ""
    End With

    dgvDeletedRecords.DataSource = dv
```

Philip